# How to update shared MongoDB instance safely?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to work out how I can establish what I think needs to be a `write-lock` on a Mongo database during application startup.

I've got a setup whereby we have several (in this diagram just 2) Node API's that establish a connection to a Mongo replica set. Upon startup I want to be able to run some scripts against Mongo if it's an old version. For example:

MongoDB: `v1 schema`
Node App: `expecting v3 schema`

[image]

So during startup the Node App will run `v2Upgrade.js` and `v3Upgrade.js` or similar. However, I want to ensure that only 1 Node app can run this at any one time. So 2 questions:

Am I thinking about this in the right way?
How would I best create some sort of lock, so only 1 process runs these updates before the database is "ready"?

Comment: `db.update.insert({started: new ISODate(),version:2,by: "node1"})`. Update doc when finished with finishing date. Check before updating wether updates are currently under way. Expand to taste.